# How do i change the JavaFX TableCell color when it is selected?

Tags: colors, javafx, selected, tablecell

Well, I created a custom TableCell for my TableView.
This custom TableCell contains a Link and opens the browser when clicked.
Everything is working fine, what I want to do is change the text color of this TableCell when it is selected...
This is what I am trying to do:

```
    callback = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>(){
        @Override
        public TableCell call(TableColumn param) {
            return new TableCell<Test, String>(){
                EventHandler handler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    final AM_RSS_FX RSS = AM_RSS_FX.this;
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent param) {
                        try {
                            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(RSS.link));
                        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(AM_RSS_FX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                };
                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if(!isEmpty()){
                        final AM_RSS_FX RSS = AM_RSS_FX.this;
                        this.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
                        setText(item);
                        RSS.link = this.getText();
                        this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, handler);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void updateSelected(boolean arg0){
                    super.updateSelected(arg0);
                    if(isSelected()){
                        this.setTextFill(Color.AQUA);
                    }
                }

            };
        }
    };
```

I don't know which method i need to Override =/
I tried to Override the updateSelected, but didn't worked =/

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

1- You are adding a mouse event handler on `TableCell` instance and that event is firing when you click on it. However the table cell is still not being selected. Instead the table **row** cell selection is being fired. To enable cell selection do:

```
table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

2- No need to override `updateSelected()` to manage style, instead use CSS selectors from caspian.css:

```
.table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: lightgreen;
    -fx-text-fill: green;
}
```